# How come my implementation of these functions returns True for all cases?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm refreshing myself on how Stacks works and am doing this exercise below.

```
Write a function in python that checks if paranthesis in the string are balanced or not. Possible parantheses are "{}',"()" or "[]"

is_balanced("({a+b})")     --> True
is_balanced("))((a+b}{")   --> False
is_balanced("((a+b))")     --> True
is_balanced("))")          --> False
is_balanced("[a+b]*(x+2y)*{gg+kk}") --> True
```

I built it on top of a stack class I previously defined

```
from collections import deque

class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = deque()

    def push(self, val):
        self.stack.append(val)

    def pop(self):
        return self.stack.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.stack[-1]

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.stack) == 0
    
    def size(self):
        return len(self.stack)

    def is_match(self, ch1, ch2):
        match_dict = {
            ')':'(',
            ']':'[',
            '}':'{',
        }
        return match_dict[ch1] == ch2

    def is_balanced(self, string):
        for char in string:
            if char == '(' or char == '{' or char == '[':
                self.push(char)
            if char == ')' or char == '}' or char == ']':
                if self.is_empty():
                    return False
                if self.is_match(char, self.pop()):
                    return True
```

And here's the answer to the exercise

```
from collections import deque

def is_match(ch1, ch2):
    match_dict = {
        ')': '(',
        ']': '[',
        '}': '{',
    }
    return match_dict[ch1] == ch2


def is_balanced(s):
    stack = deque()
    for ch in s:
        if ch == '(' or ch == '{' or ch == '[':
            stack.append(ch)
        if ch == ')' or ch == '}' or ch == ']':
            if len(stack) == 0:
                return False
            if is_match(ch, stack.pop()):
                return True
```

Other than the obvious differences, I feel like my implementation is 1:1
However, here's my result:

```
True
True
True
True
True
```

And here's the result I'm supposed to get:

```
True
False
True
False
True
```

Using the debugger, I noticed that the length of the my stack is never 0, unlike the length of the answers stack, which is definitely part of the reason I'm not getting False, but I don't know how to fix it.

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you `return True` where you do?

Comment: Also, re-check your output. Even with this error, the output is not always `True`. Literally copy-pasting your code, `is_balanced("))((a+b}{")` returns `False`. Please make sure your question is consistent, as it can make it harder to find the error. (It is also sufficient to use `list` to implement a stack, not `deque`, but this is not a breaking error.)

Comment: Not reproducible. Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/AngrySophisticatedLine

Comment: Both answers are incorrect: You returned True when there is a first match. You need to wait until you exhaust the string. At that time, if the stack is empty, you return True. Otherwise, return False.

Comment: When does `stack = deque()` happen in the provided code? When does `self.stack = deque()` happen in your code? If you use the same stack for multiple inputs, do you see why this might cause a problem?

Comment: You're right! You saying this really opened my eyes to the problem I was having. Thank you @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 1):

In your algorithm, when there is a match (e.g. [ and ]), then you return `True` right away. That is not correct, consider this case: "[]]".

My approach:

1. Scan the expression string, char by char
2. If there is an opening bracket, push to the stack (a simple list)
3. If there is a closing bracket, check for match:

   - If the stack is empty, meaning we have a closing bracket without a matching opening, return `False` right away
   - If not matched, return `False` right away
   - If matched then move on
4. When all chars exhausted, check the stack:

   - An empty stack means all brackets matched, return `True`
   - A non-empty stack means there are more opening than closing, return `False`

```py
def is_balanced(expr: str) -> bool:
    """Return True if the expression is balanced with brackets."""
    opening = "([{<"
    closing = ")]}>"
    pairs = dict(zip(opening, closing))
    stack = []
    
    for c in expr:
        if c in opening:
            stack.append(c)
        elif c in closing:
            try:
                c_open = stack.pop()
            except IndexError:
                # Case: Found the closing without opening
                return False
            if pairs[c_open] != c:
                # Case: mismatched opening and closing
                return False
            
    # A non-empty stack means there are opening without closing
    return not stack
```